# JQuery AJAX response returning only [object Object] and Undefined in C# ASP.NET

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, json

I have seen this question has been asked so many times, but please try to understand what is my actual problem.

---

My JavaScript codes are :

```
     $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: 'ScheduleCampiagn.aspx/GetTemplate',
            data: '{TempId: ' + $('#<%=ddl_Select_Template.ClientID%>').val() + '}',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (response) {
                alert(response);
            },
            failure: function (response) {

            }
        });
```

And my GetTemplate function in ScheduleCampiagn.aspx.cs is:

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
public static List<TemplateClass> GetTemplate(int TempId)
{
    List<TemplateClass> dataTemp = new List<TemplateClass>();
    TemplateClass temp = new TemplateClass();
    String cmd = "Select Tmpl_Id,Tmpl_Body_Content from TBL_DESIGN_TEMPLETE WHERE Tmpl_Id='" + TempId + "'";
    DataSet dsTemp = new DataSet();
    dsTemp.Clear();
    con.Retrive(cmd, ref dsTemp);
    cmd = string.Empty;
    temp.TempId = Convert.ToInt32(dsTemp.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Tmpl_Id"]);
    temp.TempContent = Convert.ToString(dsTemp.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Tmpl_Body_Content"]);
    dataTemp.Add(temp);
    return dataTemp;
}
```

The GetTemplate function returns only one row as I Expected. But my problems are:

---

1.when it is executing alert box shown with content as [object Object].

2.when i change the success function as 
            alert(response[0].TempId);
        it shows that response is undefiend

3.i also debug the js code with FireBug It is showing ReferenceError: response is undefiened.

4.i also tried with response.d to get the value, but it is not working.

### I only want to fetch the content of dataTemp i:e

---

```
        1.dataTemp.TempId

        2.dataTemp.TempContent
```

Please help me on this or kindly let me know what i have missed in these code, I have already lost 1 whole day by searching it.

Thank you very much

Comment: Since you have firebug you can use `console.log` instead of `alert` to see what the actual object contains - then in the firebug console you can see the object.  You can also see the object in the network tab > find the ajax call > look at the response

Comment: I think you need to return response of type `json` from your `webmethod` as you ajax is expecting the same...

Comment: yes i got an error that is ReferenceError: response is undefiened

Comment: you can see the actual object in debug window (F12 for chrome), put a break point  vbefore alert.

Comment: Why are you returning a list if you only need to return a single item?

Comment: try  alert(response.d.[0].TempId);

Comment: i also think so @Guruprasad Rao, but how any suggestion from your side

Comment: **[This Link](http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/96/handling-json-arrays-returned-from-asp-net-web-services-with-jquery)** might be useful

Comment: @sudhAnsu63: you could post it as answer

Comment: I agree with @sudhAnsu63 too!! Try his suggestion once!!

Comment: i have also tried by returning a string from webmethod but i got the same

Comment: @Tufan, wrapping response in `.d` helps protecting against CSRF type of attacks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Response is wrapped inside d property.

```
$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: 'ScheduleCampiagn.aspx/GetTemplate',
            data: '{TempId: ' + $('#<%=ddl_Select_Template.ClientID%>').val() + '}',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (response) {
                // fail-safe for older ASP.NET frameworks
                var data = response.hasOwnProperty("d") ? response.d : response;
                alert(data.TempId);  //Changed here
            },
            failure: function (response) {

            }
        });
```

Code behind method.

```
//Changed the return type to a single object instead of list.
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
public static TemplateClass GetTemplate(int TempId)
{

    TemplateClass temp = new TemplateClass();
    String cmd = "Select Tmpl_Id,Tmpl_Body_Content from TBL_DESIGN_TEMPLETE WHERE Tmpl_Id='" + TempId + "'";
    DataSet dsTemp = new DataSet();
    dsTemp.Clear();
    con.Retrive(cmd, ref dsTemp);
    cmd = string.Empty;
    temp.TempId = Convert.ToInt32(dsTemp.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Tmpl_Id"]);
    temp.TempContent = Convert.ToString(dsTemp.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Tmpl_Body_Content"]);

    return temp;
}
```

Comment: i didnt see the code-behind change. I think he want to return list anyway

Comment: yes it is working nicely, thank you so much, but how i did not understand it properly

Comment: [Check this link](http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/96/handling-json-arrays-returned-from-asp-net-web-services-with-jquery) also given by @GuruPrasad

Comment: [Here is more details reagarding .d Encapsulation](http://encosia.com/never-worry-about-asp-net-ajaxs-d-again/)